# Any source for commonly restricted keywords for usernames?

Tags: user-accounts, account-management

I'm working on a web service and need to restrict users from signing up with certain usernames such as admin, root, etc.

I know this is a common problem that everyone goes through when developing a new service, so thought there should be a database or at least some examples of commonly banned usernames for websites, but couldn't find it on Google. I guess I'm not searching it with the right keyword.

Can anyone point to a resource on this?

Comment: What is your criteria for 'banned', that they have a traditional meaning in an industry, are already used in your system, are swearwords?

Comment: What did you end up finding?

Answer (score 3):

I found this on google http://fffff.at/googles-official-list-of-bad-words/

And alot of other results, I dont know if you just want to copy and paste into your own script or read it just to get an idea of what words they ban.

If you are going to implement this yourself, be aware of [the Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).
Which basically is when decent words get banned because they have a badword in the spelling.

Judging by your post you want this for usernames, I would then let them create the user (if it doesn't exist ofc) but send a notice to moderator, if it really is a badword then force namechange and ban until done.